# How to save SMS in android

Tags: android, sms, android-contentresolver

I want to save SMS to inbox and I have implemented answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642076/how-to-save-sms-to-inbox-in-android) which were supposed to store message into inbox. But I'm unable to find the stored sms and no error or exception is thrown.
Thanks

Comment: check this link for SmsManager class [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager)

Comment: @sahil thanks, but I am not seeking to send SMS, I just want to save it.

Comment: you can only send or read the sms. what you intend to do can be done by the inbuilt app only.

Answer (score 0):

Only the default SMS app can write to the SMS database on modern versions of Android.  You can send an SMS, or read them.  But only 1 app set by the user can write them.

Comment: woo! That is quite sad. Thanks for clarifying that. Please, I would like to know what versions or API levels are affected.

Comment: Anything KitKat and above should have this restriction, but there were loopholes on KitKat that allowed you to still do it.  Starting with Lollipop these were removed.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

So I did a little more digging and found a way around it.

I had to make my app the default SMS app using information from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38975806/android-how-to-make-my-app-default-sms-app-programatically) then I was able to get the code working.