# Read Incoming SMS on Android KitKat and up

Tags: android

I am trying to create an app that checks for a certain code on incoming SMS messages. Before Android KitKat everything was working fine. The old way of doing it is by creating a `BroadcastReceiver`, registering it in the Manifest, asking for permissions, etc.

However, this does not always (most of the time) works on Android KitKat and up. Even if you put the highest value in the priority field, the default SMS app on the phone will always receive the SMS and will block other apps from accessing it. The obvious solution for this one is to make an SMS app and make it as default. But this is not the whole purpose of making my app.

Is there any workaround on this limitation? Or is this the end-point?

Answer (score 3):

Ref: [Android - how to make my app default sms app programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38975806/android-how-to-make-my-app-default-sms-app-programatically)

Not according to the code in your question. Let's review the four requirements from [the blog pos](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html)t:

> In a broadcast receiver, include an intent filter for
>   SMS_DELIVER_ACTION ("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER"). The
>   broadcast receiver must also require the BROADCAST_SMS permission.

You have this, in the form of your PhoneStateReceiver.

> In a broadcast receiver, include an intent filter for
>   WAP_PUSH_DELIVER_ACTION
>   ("android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_DELIVER") with the MIME type
>   "application/vnd.wap.mms-message". The broadcast receiver must also
>   require the BROADCAST_WAP_PUSH permission.

You do not have this.

> In your activity that delivers new messages, include an intent filter
>   for ACTION_SENDTO ("android.intent.action.SENDTO") with schemas, sms:,
>   smsto:, mms:, and mmsto:.

You have this, in the form of DashboardActivity.

> In a service, include an intent filter for ACTION_RESPONSE_VIA_MESSAGE
>   ("android.intent.action.RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE") with schemas, sms:,
>   smsto:, mms:, and mmsto:. This service must also require the
>   SEND_RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE permission.

You have this, in the form of HeadlessSmsSendService.

> So, add a  for WAP_PUSH_DELIVER_ACTION, following the
>   instructions, and see if that helps.

Ref: [Android – Listen For Incoming SMS Messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089313/android-listen-for-incoming-sms-messages)

```
public class SmsListener extends BroadcastReceiver{

    private SharedPreferences preferences;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")){
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();           //---get the SMS message passed in---
            SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
            String msg_from;
            if (bundle != null){
                //---retrieve the SMS message received---
                try{
                    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                    msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                    for(int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                        msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                        msg_from = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                        String msgBody = msgs[i].getMessageBody();
                    }
                }catch(Exception e){
//                            Log.d("Exception caught",e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: In your manifest file add the BroadcastReceiver-

```
<receiver android:name=".listener.SmsListener">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Add this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

OR

> Note that on some devices your code wont work without
>   android:priority="1000" in intent filter:

```
<receiver android:name=".listener.SmsListener">
    <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And here is some optimizations:

```
public class SmsListener extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            for (SmsMessage smsMessage : Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(intent)) {
                String messageBody = smsMessage.getMessageBody();
            }
        }
    }
}
Note: The value must be an integer, such as "100". Higher numbers have a higher priority. The default value is 0. The value must be greater than -1000 and less than 1000.
```

Here's a link.

For More : [Android – Listen For Incoming SMS Messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089313/android-listen-for-incoming-sms-messages)

Comment: Please explain exactly how this solves the OP's issue.

Comment: i will edited my que and added more information @MikeM.